# x-axis get over written in matplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am working on my dataset and I have to plot the cdf of it. I already did but due to large number of data the x-axis showing some overwritten values. Could anyone help me in this regard. my code is

```
import csv
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter
import collection

x = []
y=[]
row=[]
with open('SCPS-ADAPTIVE-1e8.csv', 'r') as file:
   reader = csv.reader(file)
   for row in reader:
      y.append(row[1])
N=len(y)
data = np.sort(y)
P = np.arange(N) / float(N)
plt.plot(data, P, marker='o')
plt.show (
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Most likely your x-data are strings instead of float values. Convert them when importing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide data so we cannot replicate your chart. However, this is what I would try:

```py
# increase or decrease this variable to satisfy your needs
num_labels = 30
ticks = [t for t in range(N) if t % num_labels == 0]
labels = [l for i, l in enumerate(data) if i % num_labels == 0]
plt.xticks(ticks, labels)
```